# How to response on a Windows command line prompt?

Tags: perl, batch-file

I am trying to write a Windows batch file that executes a program which works fine. However the executed program (.exe) stops and requires the user to enter `Yes` before it proceeds.

Is there a way I can send `Yes` automatically to the console application?

The code I'm writing is to pass around 2,000 files through this particular executable and every one of them requires the `Yes` response to continue.

I've tried using echo `Yes`. I've tried doing a sleep then echo `Yes`, but these do not work. Is there any other way to do this?

You should be aware that the Windows batch file is actually being written by a Perl script. The Perl script takes the list of files, constructs the required command line commands, then output's them to a .bat file via a command line re-direct. This .bat file is then executed manually. My Perl code is:

```
$inFile = 'fileList.txt';
$key = '"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"';

open(IN, "< $inFile");
while (<IN>) {
  chop();
  printf ("RunMe.exe --key %s \"%s\"\n",$key,$_);
  printf("del \"%s.bak\"\n",$_);
}
close(IN);
```

Open to suggestions on how I might be able to achieve this.

Comment: Sometimes appending `<Yes` on the command line on calling a console application works. But it depends on how `RunMe.exe` processes user input.

Comment: Is the environment MS-DOS actually or Windows command prompt? In case of Windows you could just emulate keys being pressed. I think this would be also doable in DOS by modyfing typeahead buffer but frankly my DOS programming years are long gone and I am not sure about this

Comment: This is Windows  command prompt nut in essence the same thing as msdos (more or less).  Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

The ['yes' command] will echo 'y' (or whatever you ask it to) indefinitely.  Use it as:

```
'yes | command-that-asks-for-input'
```

or, if a capital 'Y' is required:

```
'yes Y | command-that-asks-for-input'
```